# Req/Res Express Design

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, express

I need to make more requests to Amazon S3 in one browser refresh.

I havent specify problem, but I've design problem.

-

(1) User fill the form and push submit button

(2) **Make request** to S3 and get specific file

(3) **Get file in response**, Edit it

(4) Send file to S3 in **next request**

```
    // Make first request
    s3.client.putObject(options, function(err) {

        // Get a response
        s3.client.getObject(options, function(err, data) {

            // Make next request
            s3.client.putObject(options, function(err, data) {
            }

        }

    }
```

Is is possible to make more request in one refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do something like

```
app.post('/foo', function(req, res){
    //perform any form stuff necessary

    // Make first request
    s3.client.putObject(options, function(err) {

    // Get a response
    s3.client.getObject(options, function(err, data) {

        // Make next request
        s3.client.putObject(options, function(err, data) {
              res.write(stuff);
        });

    });

   });
});
```